# Docker with no containers creating bridges on startup

Tags: linux, docker

I have Docker installed on an embedded system, and the run script that starts docker ends with

```
dockerd --bridge:none &
```

if I boot the device and start docker with that script, then I end up with a bridge network created at 172.18.0.1 and this cannot happen.

if I run the same start up script with out the `--bridge` flag, I get two bridges at start up, with the second named docker0 at 172.17.0.1. so the `--bridge` flag is somewhat working, but all documentation points to other bridge coming from a `docker create network` command, or container started with certain flags, but this instance has no containers and no images, it creates this bridge as soon and dockerd is run and there seems to be nothing I can do about it.

I tried modifying the start script to add the `--internal` flag as well, but this had no effect

Answer (score 0):

Create or edit the `/etc/docker/daemon.json` file with the following content:

```
{
    "bridge": "none"
}
```

Afterwards, restart the Docker service

```
systemctl restart docker
```

Comment: I said I've already done this. and the does get rid of the bridge called docker0 ,but not the bridge named a random MAC address